# Find common alphabets in two strings using for loop

Tags: java

I am trying to find the common characters in two strings just by using the for loop. The below code is working fine, if I provide two completely different strings ex.one and two but if I provide two strings with same input ex.teen and teen it doesn't work as expected.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CommonAlphabets {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try(Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)){
            System.out.println("Enter String one ");
            String stringOne = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter String two ");
            String StringTwo = input.nextLine();

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            for(int i=0;i<stringOne.length();i++){
                for(int j=0;j<StringTwo.length();j++){
                    if(stringOne.charAt(i)== StringTwo.charAt(j)){
                        sb.append(stringOne.charAt(i));
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Common characters are " +sb.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Should I create another nested for loop to find duplicates in the StringBuffer or is there a better way to handle this scenario.

Comment: Define "working fine". Define "doesn't work as expected".

Comment: what is the expected output for all of your cases?

Comment: working fine meaning the common character for input ex. one and two is displayed as o, whereas for input teen and teen is displayed as teeeen.

Comment: @gowthamjs23 Think of repetitive characters and how you're parsing the strings. Try debug :)

Comment: for StringOne=teen & String2=teen, output should be ten? or teen?

Comment: It should be ten.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need an inner for loop but use `contains` instead

```
    String stringOne = "one";
    String stringTwo = "one";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i=0;i<stringOne.length() && i < stringTwo.length ();i++){
           if(stringOne.contains(String.valueOf(stringTwo.charAt(i))) &&
                   !sb.toString().contains(String.valueOf(stringTwo.charAt(i)))){  
                                                      // check already added
                sb.append(stringTwo.charAt(i));
           }
    }
    System.out.println (sb.toString());
```

**edit**

check to make sure `char` to be added does not already exist in StringBuilder - 
Could use a `Set` instead

If using a `Set`

`Set<Character> set = new HashSet<> ();`

your logic could be simplified to

```
if(stringOne.contains(String.valueOf(stringTwo.charAt(i)))){
     set.add(stringTwo.charAt(i));
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter, please always mention why you downvoted someone's comment/question/answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Set for it.

```
    Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
    for(int i = 0; i<stringOne.length(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < StringTwo.length(); j++) {
            if(stringOne.charAt(i) == StringTwo.charAt(j)){
                set.add(stringOne.charAt(i));
            }
        }
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Character c : set) {
        sb.append(c);
    }
    System.out.println("Common characters are " + sb);
```

Answer (score 0):

well your approach is fine as the result is showing what you are expecting there fore that code is fine, but you need to stop the duplication , therefore you have to write the code for 'sb' variable so that it will remove duplicates or write code in loop so that it wont provide duplicate.
as your code is becoming complicated to read so i would prefer that you make a method to write code to remove duplicate it will go like

```
static void removeDuplicate(StringBuilder s){
    for(int i=0,i<s.length-1,i++){
        for(int j=i+1,j<s.length,j++){
            if(s.charAt(i)==s.charAt(j)){
                 s.deleteCharAt(j);
            }
        }
  }
```

call this method before printing

Answer (score 0):

Another approach you could try is - combine the two input strings, iterate over the concatenated string and return the characters which exist in both the strings.

Using a `Set` will ensure you do not add characters which get repeated due to the concatenation of the strings.

Here's what I wrote -

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class HelloWorld {

     private static Character[] findCommonLetters(String combined, String w1, String w2) {
         HashSet<Character> hash = new HashSet<>();
         for(char c: combined.toCharArray()) {
             if(w1.indexOf(c) != -1 && w2.indexOf(c) != -1) {
                 hash.add(c);
             }
         }
         return hash.toArray(new Character[hash.size()]);
     }
     public static void main(String []args){

        // System.out.println("Hello World");
        String first = "flour";
        String second = "four";
        String combined = first.concat(second);
        Character[] result = findCommonLetters(combined, first, second);
        for(char c: result) {
            System.out.print(c);
        }
        System.out.println();

     }
}
```

Demo [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java8_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMZHlsNXRJOVZaTzg).

Answer (score -1):

This is the best way to do this because it's time complexity is `n` so that why this is the best you could do.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CommonAlphabets
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in))
    {
        System.out.println("Enter String one ");
        String stringOne = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter String two ");
        String StringTwo = input.nextLine();

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        /**
         * Assuming char as index of array where A-Z is from index 0 to 25 and a-z is index 26-51
         */
        int[] alphabetArray1 = new int[52];
        for(int i = 0, len = stringOne.length(); i < len; i++)
            alphabetArray1[stringOne.charAt(i) > 94 ? stringOne.charAt(i) - 71 : stringOne.charAt(i) - 65] = 1;

        int[] alphabetArray2 = new int[52];
        for(int i = 0, len = StringTwo.length(); i < len; i++)
            alphabetArray2[StringTwo.charAt(i) > 94 ? StringTwo.charAt(i) - 71 : StringTwo.charAt(i) - 65] = 1;

//          System.out.println(Arrays.toString(alphabetArray1));
//          System.out.println(Arrays.toString(alphabetArray2));

        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
            if (alphabetArray1[i] == 1 && alphabetArray2[i] == 1)
                sb.append((char) (i < 26 ? i + 65 : i + 71));

        System.out.println("Common characters are " + sb.toString());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, But compare the time complexity of your Code VS Mine.
Mine is `n` and your's is `n^2`

Comment: The strings are `teen and teen` - for this readability is definitely better

Comment: No my dear, For long runs and scalability complexity comes first.

Comment: LOL, your code was so complex it had hard to notice bugs in it

Comment: No dear, It's just a formula am using. It is not at all complex if you know the formula.

Comment: `Enter String one 
test123
Enter String two 
test23
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -16
 at Main.main(Main.java:31)
`

Comment: Please read the question carefully, the question asks for  CommonAlphabets and not characters so i.e. either A-Z OR a-z. Addition, if you want to do this for CommonCharacters, you have the idea from my code and so modify it. Or else let me know, I'll do the modification for you :)

Comment: I concede your point - so does the OP state that this should be limited to the Latin Alphabet only?

Comment: My code is specific to `English Characters`. when we know what kind of data we are going to get as input stream then yes we can customise a general solution as per specific requirement, which I did for english alphabet so as to improve throughput/efficiency/time-complexity. For number string or alphaNumeric Strings this is the best way as per me. Regarding all Latin or unicode characters either we need another data structure(can design) or some other algorithm to get linear time complexity.